# Magento 1.9 running slow after migrating to new database server

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I migrated our Magento 1.9 to a new mysql and now I noticed that the site is loading super slow.

When I login to mysql and run a show processlist I see a long running query

```
SELECT `e`.*, IF(at_is_active.value_id > 0, at_is_active.value, at_is_active_default.value) AS `is_a
```

I am not sure what this query is and why its running so many times in a row and so slow.

Anyone know how to fix. I ssh'ed into the site and reindex'ed via ssh but that did not fix the issue. 
The website is a Magento 1.9 on php 7 and have read that the magento database repair toll does not wok with php7. Anyone experience this and able to fix it?

Comment: how many products do you have in your Catalog? Is your new mySql server optimized for it configuration. What is the latency between your DB and Web server?

Comment: We have 1160 products and the server and the database server are both in the same Amazon AWS region (to cut down on latency) also the database server is optimized and never had issues prior to us moving from having the mysql on the same server as the file server. now we moved the mysql to amazon rds and all of a sudden the mysql is slow and we see a bunch of those queries as listed above.

Comment: have you upgraded mysql from 5.6 to 5.7 ?

Comment: 1160 products  should not take too long to index, could you run show full processlist and see if the query is still persisting? I am under the assumption that your server is on EC2.